# Is "Why is inside-r.org pointing at mran.microsoft.com?" on topic on Cross Validated?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, r, software, references

Are general R related questions such as the one in the title of this question on topic on crossvalidated? I presume they're not.

I was looking for a specific tutorial at inside-r.org but now the website just redirects me to mran.microsoft.com and tutorials are nowhere to be seen. Google still shows results from inside-r.org but each page redirect to Microsoft's new website. I'm having trouble understanding what has happened...

UPDATE:
inside-r.org is gone. Please check this article for more information.
https://www.r-bloggers.com/farewell-inside-r-org-where-to-find-alternative-r-resources/

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Revolution Analytics is (was?) a private company. They may have sold themselves to Microsoft.

Comment: @gung It appears to be the case. Not having positive feelings towards Microsoft right now :(

Comment: This (the purchase of revolution analytics by Microsoft) happened quite a while ago.

Comment: Here is a reference: [A message from our CEO David Rich on joining Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20150408234423/http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/a-message-from-our-ceo-david-rich-on-joining-microsoft).

Comment: Curiously, it seems you can still access the blog directly (e.g., [here is the post for August 10, 2016](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/08/in-case-you-missed-it-july-2016-roundup.html)--i.e., today), but the *Revolution Analytics* heading does not display.

Answer (score 7):

It's [off topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, and I doubt this particular discussion (aside from the question of on-topicness) would be on topic at any of the other SE network sites.

You're free to raise it on our chat if you wish.

Comment: Ok @Glen_b , should I close the question?

Comment: @mickkk This question? No, the opening paragraph (about what's on topic on the main site) is on topic for meta.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.